# How to change a program path/alias?

Tags: linux, path, imagemagick, alias

I'm not sure how it works on Linux, but you can type in program names such as `ls`, `man`, etc., in any directory and the programs are executed.

I uninstalled an old version of ImageMagick and built the new version, and now when I try executing the `convert` command (which runs ImageMagick) I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/convert: No such file or directory
```

So I ran:

```
find / -name convert
```

Which showed this:

```
/usr/local/bin/convert
```

So it appears that for some reason ImageMagick put the actual executable in a different directory this time around, but when I try running the program it looks in the old directory.

How can I update the `convert` path/alias/shortcut (terminology fail) with the new path?

Comment: You could try making a symbolic link between the new path and the old path. This feels like a bit of a hack, but it's probably less likely to break things than attempting a move.

Alternatively you could look at build options for ImageMagick and see if there's a path you can change when building

Comment: Put `/usr/local/bin` in your path?

Comment: @DavidPostill You mean the `$PATH` variable? If so, it's already in there: `/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin`

Comment: What is the output of `ls -al /usr/local/bin/convert`? and what is the output of `alias`?

Comment: @DavidPostill The output of that command is `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 24743 Nov 28 21:57 /usr/local/bin/convert*`. The output of alias is quite long, but there's nothing for `convert` in it.

Comment: @Crippledsmurf From this post, http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=15598#p55366, it appears `/usr/local/bin` is actually the "right"  location for the `convert` program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that your `/usr/local/bin/` directory is in your `$PATH`:

```
echo $PATH
```

This should return all directories where your Bash searches for executables, separated by colons (**"`:`"**). The output should look similar to this:

```
/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin
```

The Bash shell uses *'hash table'* to remember the full pathnames of executable files. For details see `man bash` and search for *'SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS'*.

It may happen that after a new installation of programs, that this hash table is not updated automatically. To enforce this update in the current terminal, use this command:

```
hash -r
```

Now
    which convert

should return

```
/usr/local/bin/convert
```